# How can I efficiently calculate the inverse of this symmetric near-tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices

I'm interested in calculating the inverse of the following matrix in order to solve a system of linear equations.

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}
b & a & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a\\
a & b & a & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & a & b & a & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & a & b & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & a & b & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & a & b & a\\
a & 0 & 0 & 0 & a & b
\end{pmatrix}$$

This matrix is almost tridiagonal, except for entries in the top-right and bottom-left corners. I have seen how to calculate the inverse of tridiagonal matrix, but how would those corner-entries affect the inverse?

By the way, this matrix shows up in the Crank-Nicolson method applied to parabolic PDE's (diffusion equation particularly) with periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: Depending on condition Woodbury identity or an iterative solver

Comment: @user251257 Could you elaborate on how I could use an iterative solver? And what do you mean "depending on condition"? Do you mean "depending on your computational tools"?

Comment: the woodbury identity is not that stable. So a bad conditioned matrix (or the the tridiagonal part)  makes the identity useless for numerical application. There is a large range of iterative solvers. For example, Jacobi method is pretty simple but usually slow.

Comment: ah, sorry, i have made an error. Do you really need the inverse? Don't you just need to solve linear equations with that matrix?

Comment: @user251257 Yes, that is what I need. I'll edit this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that you want to solve $Ax = b$, and you are not iterested in the inverse $A^{-1}$ (which is dense).

You may perform the LQ factorization of $A$ (or QR of $A'$) using Givens rotations. In this case $n$ rotations are required. Then resulting $L$ matrix is lower triangular with two subdiagonals except the last row of $L$, which is dense and must be stored separately. The matrix $Q$ cannot be formed explicitly, since is dense. Required decomposition can be performed in $O(n^2)$ operations.

Answer (score 0):

The Sherman-Morris formula can be used for this type of matrix
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved efficiently by using the Thomas algorithm. The Wikipedia page does a pretty good job on explaining it. For your case of periodic boundary, you may need to spend a little bit more time to look for a better explanation.